# Implementing non blocking request in PHP. Howto

Tags: php

The problem I face now is that I do not know how to implement non-blocking requests in PHP. In my application any user activity is archived and this archiving process may take some significant time - up to 5-10 seconds. Because of this user interface (which is in JavaScript) is no longer responsive since it also depends on requests to server. So, suppose I made a request to the server like this (using `ExtJS` library which does not matter here):

```
  Ext.Ajax.request({
      url:'/handlers/archive.php', // my handler which I want to make non-blocking
      method:'POST',
      params:{...} // some parameters submitted to the server
  });
  ... here are other multiple request to the server 
  ... they are now waiting for the completion of heavy archive.php procedure
```

So, how to make this php procedure truly non-blocking? Any working example of a non-blocking procedure will be extremely helpful.

Comment: "Blocking PHP" is not really the problem. The problem is simply that one request *takes too long*. You could speed up the work PHP has to do by doing the slow tasks later; e.g. you put some data somewhere and let a cron job do the slow tasks later based on that data.

Answer (score 1):

if you want your client to get a fast response and keep working on the data in the server side you'll have to implement some mechanism for this

for example :

1. get POST request from client
2. write data into DB / queue / filesystem
3. return 200 response to client
4. other process will query the DB later on archive it (the 5-10 seconds)

you can use RabbitMq or any other queue system / message systems

Answer (score 1):

Truly [multi-threaded PHP](http://docs.php.net/Thread) is tricky in a web-app unless your web server is set up to handle it, e.g. via [Apache's MPM Worker](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/worker.html).

In this case, I think your best bet is to use exec() to [fork a curl command](https://segment.com/blog/how-to-make-async-requests-in-php/):

```
$req = "curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json'";
$req.= " -d '" . $payload . "' " . "'" . $url . "'";
$req .= " > /dev/null 2>&1 &";
exec($req);
```